# Turn off a feature if the server is loaded with requests

Tags: javascript

I am working on implementing an auto save feature and was looking for some suggestions on how to implement a roll back strategy incase the server is bombarded with requests and there's increase in response time . 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you expecting to have a high number of users use your product?

Comment: yes . There could be around 108000 requests each hour . Is there a way to find out on server side so that it could send out a flag to turn off the auto save on the UI side ?